# Gson to Java - Map

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Eu preciso passar esses valores de um arquivo json para um de classe java,o arquivo Json é desse tipo:

```
{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Gold",
        "description":"Shiny!",
        "spriteId":1,
        "consumable":true,
        "effectsId":[1]
    },
```

Eu criei um map desse jeito:

```
Items i = new Items();


        Map<String, Items> mapaNomes = new HashMap<String, Items>();
        mapaNomes.put("Gold",i);
        mapaNomes.put("Apple",i );
        mapaNomes.put("Clain Mail",i );
```

O problema é quando esta lendo o arquivo json,eu comecei a programa em android agora e devo estar esquecendo ou errando algo bem básico,alguem sabe o porque o inputStreamReader não está legal?

```
BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        Items Items = gson.fromJson((BufferedReader) mapaNomes, Items.class);
```

Comment: Este é o SOpt, por favor traduza sua pergunta para o português.

Comment: I need that you perceive that this comunidade fala português.

Comment: Nem vi que estava português,viajei hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro: o seu reader não está lendo de um arquivo e sim da entrada padrão (System.in).

Segundo: você está fazendo cast de um HashMap para um BufferedReader, isso é a mesma coisa que fazer cast de Cachorro para Maçaneta. Não vai funcionar meeeeesmo.

Uma forma de fazer seria assim:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"));
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Items items = gson.fromJson(in, Items.class);
mapaNomes.put(items.getNome(), items);
```